# Why there is a hole in William's shoe?

Tags: plot-explanation, falling-down

In [*Falling Down* (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106856/) there is a hole in William's shoe. I can't understand where did the hole in his shoe come from.

Comment: From walking a lot...this is just normal wear and tear on cheap shoes. Is there some deeper question here I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

The hole is from walking, after his car broke down.  It is just one in a steady stream of struggles that William went through, which leads to his eventual breakdown.